# Getting number of times values appear together SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to write an SQL Server Query that returns the number of times that items apear together in orders. The tables are layed out as so:

ORDERS TABLE

```
Id    |    OrderId    |    Date
-----------------------------------
0001  |     589555    |    1/1/2018
0002  |     609510    |    1/1/2018
```

ORDERS ITEMS TABLE

```
Id    |    OrderId    |    ItemId
-----------------------------------
0001  |     589555    |    KP8
0002  |     589555    |    GH7
0003  |     589555    |    FR9
0004  |     609510    |    KP8
0005  |     609510    |    RFG
0006  |     609510    |    FR9
0007  |     609510    |    KP8
```

ITEMS TABLE

```
Id    |    ItemId
---------------------
1     |    KP8
2     |    RFG
3     |    FR9
4     |    GH7
```

What I am trying to get at is how many times specific items are ordered on the same order as other items, like so:

```
KP8 | RFG | 10
KP8 | FR9 | 5
KP8 | GH7 | 2
RFG | KP8 | 10
RFG | FR9 | 7
RFG | GH7 | 1

etc, etc, etc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Running SQL Server 2014

Comment: The table stucture is not the best here, I would have recommended adding a junction table between Items and Orders tables as they have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: your result is confusing... why would KP8 be the anchor for repeat orders.. should be the order number and count orders of the same type.

Comment: There's more tables, Orders Table | Orders Items Table | and another table that holds the items. The above is just a shortened description.

Comment: Alright, did an edit on the post to show the other relation - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following.

```
DECLARE @Order TABLE(Id varchar(100),      OrderId   varchar(100),    ItemId varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Order
VALUES
('0001'  ,     '589555'    ,    'KP8'),
('0002'  ,     '589555'    ,    'GH7'),
('0003'  ,     '589555'    ,    'FR9'),
('0004'  ,     '609510'    ,    'KP8'),
('0005'  ,     '609510'    ,    'RFG'),
('0006'  ,     '609510'    ,    'FR9'),
('0007'  ,     '609510'    ,    'KP8')


SELECT T1.ItemId Item1, T2.ItemId Item2, Count(*) AS Count FROM
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemId) R1 FROM @Order
) T1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemId) R2 FROM @Order
 )T2 ON  T1.OrderId=T2.OrderId AND T1.ItemId <> T2.ItemId AND R1> R2

GROUP BY T1.ItemId, T2.ItemId
```

**Output:**

```
  Item1 Item2   Count
  GH7   FR9     1
  KP8   FR9     3 
  RFG   FR9     1
  KP8   GH7     1
  RFG   KP8     2
```

If you want to remove the duplicates (same item appearing multiple time in same order), you can try like following.

```
SELECT  T1.ItemId Item1, T2.ItemId Item2, Count(*) AS Count FROM
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemId) R1
    FROM
      (
       SELECT DISTINCT ITEMID,ORDERID  FROM @Order 
      ) T
) T1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemId) R2 
    FROM
      (
       SELECT DISTINCT ITEMID,ORDERID  FROM @Order 
      ) T
 )T2 ON  T1.OrderId=T2.OrderId AND T1.ItemId <> T2.ItemId AND R1> R2

GROUP BY T1.ItemId, T2.ItemId
```

**Output**

```
Item1   Item2   Count
GH7     FR9         1
KP8     FR9         2
RFG     FR9         1
KP8     GH7         1
RFG     KP8         1
```

Working Sample [rextester](http://rextester.com/JSQJR51030)